# How to handle POST array having multiple objects from Ajax Api in Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am using Ajax POST method with Laravel Api,  whenever I click submit it shows "500 internal server error" and in Laravel, it shows the "GET method not allowed for this route. Supported method POST".

Actually, when I use this Ajax method with this type of array `{"status":0,"product_id":"62","company":"Whitel","orignal_qty":"8"}` **It Works**.

But in this case, the array contains more than one object. I need to use Loop in Laravel Controller but I don't know how to handle multiple array objects.

Here is my code...

`var myArrJSON = [{"status":0,"product_id":"62","company":"Whitel","orignal_qty":"8"},{"status":0,"product_id":"55","company":"Wow","orignal_qty":"9"}]`

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: "http://localhost/spe-api/public/api/net/store",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: myArrJSON,
  success:function(response){
    alert('success');
  },
  error:function(response){ 
    alert('error');
  }
});
```

Here is Laravel code...

`Route::post('/net/store', 'NetController@netStoreData');`

```
public function netStoreData(Request $request, Net $net) {
  $data = [];
  $data = $request->all();
  foreach($data->values as $item) {
    $data['status'] = $item->status;
    $data['product_id'] = $item->product_id;
    $data['company'] = $item->company;
    $data['quantity'] = $item->orignal_qty;

    $net->insert($data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

**Ajax Request**

```
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "http://localhost/spe-api/public/api/net/store",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
      data : JSON.stringify(myArrJSON) 
   },
    success:function(response){
      alert('success');
    },
    error:function(response){ 
      alert('error');
    }
  });
```

**Controller**

```
  public function netStoreData(Request $request, Net $net) {
    $data = [];
    $data = json_decode($request->data);
    foreach($data->values as $item) {
      $data['status'] = $item->status;
      $data['product_id'] = $item->product_id;
      $data['company'] = $item->company;
      $data['quantity'] = $item->orignal_qty;

      $net->insert($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this by this way...

```
public function netStoreData(Request $request, Net $net) {

  $items = $request->all();
  foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    $data = [];
    $data['status'] = $item['status'];
    $data['product_id'] = $item->['product_id'];
    $data['company'] = $item->['company'];
    $data['quantity'] = $item->['quantity'];

    $net->insert($data);
  }
}
```